# Help with Deploying Trigger, Apex Test Class

Tags: apex, trigger, deployment

I've written an Apex Trigger that deletes a related object when an Opportunity is deleted but I cannot get the test class correct as to be able to pass validation and move to production.

Apex Trigger:

```
trigger deletePLScenario on Opportunity (before delete) {
    //To store parent ids

    list<id> OpportunityIds=new list<id>();

    for(Opportunity oppVar:trigger.old)
    {
        OpportunityIds.add(oppVar.id);
    } 
    //Collecting all child records related to Parent records
    list<PLNDR__PrecisionLender_Scenario__c> listOfPLS=[select id from 
                                                        PLNDR__PrecisionLender_Scenario__c where PLNDR__Opportunity__c in 
                                                        :OpportunityIds];

    system.debug('listOfPLS'+listOfPLS);
    //deleting child records

    delete listOfPLS;
}
```

Apex Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class testPlsDelete 
{    
    static testMethod void testDel() 
    {
        Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity ();

        insert testOpp;

        list<Opportunity> Opps = new list<Opportunity>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
            o.Name             = 'Testing' + i;
            o.StageName        = 'Qualification';
            o.Amount           = i * 1000000;
            o.CloseDate        = System.today() + 30;
            o.Type             = 'New Business';

        }
        insert Opps;
        update Opps;

        list<PLNDR__PrecisionLender_Scenario__c> testPls  = new list<PLNDR__PrecisionLender_Scenario__c> ();     
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            PLNDR__PrecisionLender_Scenario__c pl = new PLNDR__PrecisionLender_Scenario__c();
            insert testPls;
            update testPls;

            Test.startTest();
            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to be more specific about what is not working. We are not mind readers. If you have an error message (or multiple), please include the message(s) ***verbatim***.

Comment: Your test method doesn't delete anything. How is it going to cover a `before delete` trigger?

Comment: testmethods without asserts aren't really test methods

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your problem is in this block of code:

```
        list<PLNDR__PrecisionLender_Scenario__c> testPls  = new list<PLNDR__PrecisionLender_Scenario__c> ();   

        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            PLNDR__PrecisionLender_Scenario__c pl = new PLNDR__PrecisionLender_Scenario__c();
            insert testPls;
            update testPls;

            Test.startTest();
            Test.stopTest();
        }
```

Where you:

1. Create an empty list
2. Iterate over some random numbers
3. Create a blank object
4. Insert this object (Without setting any primary keys, or relating it to your other test data)
5. Start & end your test

It's kind of clear you don't really know what you're doing. I'd suggest going over the [trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro) Salesforce created for new developers & admins. In addition to that, going over your code with a pencil and making notes on each step, can really help you understand code better. Once you have some concrete steps, you can turn that into a test class with a little bit of work.

Lets change your test. Lets try these steps instead:

1. Create an empty list
2. Iterate over your project list
3. Create a new record, relate it to your test data from your loop, using a primary key `PLNDR__Opportunity__c` (without the key to relate the records, nothing will be returned by your query)
4. insert your list of test records
5. `assert` that there is data under each opportunity.
6. Start your test, delete your test opportunities, end your test.
7. Run your assert from step #5 again, but this time, make sure that there are 0 child records left.

---

I could write this code for you, but I think you'll learn better writing it on your own. These are the steps I would take to write the class, written out in plaintext. If you have a question on one or more of these steps, let me know, and I can add examples.

If you run into trouble writing the code, [ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new question, with a clear issue, and relevant code.